# Scrapy and proxies

Tags: python, scrapy

How do you utilize proxy support with the python web-scraping framework Scrapy?

Comment: you need to be more specific with your question...

Answer (score 54, accepted):

From the [Scrapy FAQ](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-scrapy-work-with-http-proxies),

> #### Does Scrapy work with HTTP proxies?
>
> Yes. Support for HTTP proxies is provided (since Scrapy 0.8) through the HTTP Proxy downloader middleware. See [`HttpProxyMiddleware`](http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware).

The easiest way to use a proxy is to set the environment variable `http_proxy`.  How this is done depends on your shell.

```
C:\>set http_proxy=http://proxy:port
csh% setenv http_proxy http://proxy:port
sh$ export http_proxy=http://proxy:port
```

if you want to use https proxy and visited https web,to set the environment variable `http_proxy` you should follow below,

```
C:\>set https_proxy=https://proxy:port
csh% setenv https_proxy https://proxy:port
sh$ export https_proxy=https://proxy:port
```

Comment: Thanks ... So I need to set this var before running scrapy crawler it's not possible to set it or change it from the crawler code

Comment: You can even set the proxy on a per-request base with: request.meta['proxy'] = 'http://your.proxy.address'

Comment: How do you authenticate the proxy?

Comment: @ephemient How can we tell if `scrapy` is using the proxy?

Comment: @ocean800 I use scrapy to scrape a website that shows your current IP to see if it's using the proxy.  That way I can load the page via a chrome and see my actual IP and compare it to what scrapy sees on the same page.

Answer (score 55):

**Single Proxy**

1. Enable `HttpProxyMiddleware` in your `settings.py`, like this:

   ```
   DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
       'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 1
   }
   ```
2. pass proxy to request via `request.meta`:

   ```
   request = Request(url="http://example.com")
   request.meta['proxy'] = "host:port"
   yield request
   ```

You also can choose a proxy address randomly if you have an address pool. Like this:

**Multiple Proxies**

```
class MySpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "my_spider"
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySpider, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.proxy_pool = ['proxy_address1', 'proxy_address2', ..., 'proxy_addressN']

    def parse(self, response):
        ...parse code...
        if something:
            yield self.get_request(url)

    def get_request(self, url):
        req = Request(url=url)
        if self.proxy_pool:
            req.meta['proxy'] = random.choice(self.proxy_pool)
        return req
```

Comment: The documentation says that the `HttpProxyMiddleware` is setting the proxy inside every Requests meta attr, so enabling ProxyMiddleware AND setting it manually would make no sense

Comment: I should have copied this code. I glanced it and then coded myself, but proxy functionality was not working. Now I see the proxy value was set to `request.headers` instead of `request.meta`. Stupid me (face palm)!

I went to see the `HttpProxyMiddleware` code, it skips if someone has already set `request.meta['proxy']`, so there is no need to list it in the settings https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/downloadermiddlewares/httpproxy.py

Comment: I am not sure I understand the difference between the two, is `BaseSpider` your original spider and `MySpider` or is `MySpider` is the actual modified spider and `BaseSpider `refers to `scrapy.Spider`?

Comment: Modern version does not have this field anymore ```AttributeError: 'Request' object has no attribute 'meta'```. Likely now it should look as this ```yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, meta={'proxy': proxy})```

Answer (score 33):

1-Create a new file called “middlewares.py” and save it in your scrapy project and add the following code to it.

```
import base64
class ProxyMiddleware(object):
    # overwrite process request
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        # Set the location of the proxy
        request.meta['proxy'] = "http://YOUR_PROXY_IP:PORT"

        # Use the following lines if your proxy requires authentication
        proxy_user_pass = "USERNAME:PASSWORD"
        # setup basic authentication for the proxy
        encoded_user_pass = base64.encodestring(proxy_user_pass)
        request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + encoded_user_pass
```

2 – Open your project’s configuration file (./project_name/settings.py) and add the following code

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
    'project_name.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 100,
}
```

Now, your requests should be passed by this proxy. Simple, isn’t it ?

Comment: I implement your solution which looks correct, but I keep getting a Twisted error:  twisted.web._newclient.ResponseNeverReceived: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.internet.error.ConnectionDone'>>]   ANY ADVICE???

Comment: Take care to use `base64.b64encode` instead of `base64.encodestring` as the latter adds a newline character to the encoded base64 result...! See http://stackoverflow.com/a/32243566/426790

Comment: How can we change proxy after 20 request to not to be banned?

Comment: `scrapy.contrib` is deprecated , it should be just `scrapy`

Comment: How do you get `project_name` ?

Answer (score 9):

that would be:

> export http_proxy=http://user:password@proxy:port

Comment: I use this yet I just received `[<twisted.python.failure.Failure <class 'twisted.web._newclient.ParseError'>>]`

Answer (score 4):

As I've had trouble by setting the environment in /etc/environment, here is what I've put in my spider (Python):

```
os.environ["http_proxy"] = "http://localhost:12345"
```

Comment: Might as well add ```os.environ["https_proxy"]``` to it. Worked for me having both.

Answer (score 4):

There is nice middleware written by someone   [1]: https://github.com/aivarsk/scrapy-proxies "Scrapy proxy middleware"

Answer (score 4):

Here is what I do

Method 1:

Create a Download Middleware like this

```
class ProxiesDownloaderMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        
        request.meta['proxy'] = 'user:pass@host:port'
```

and enable that in `settings.py`

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES: {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
    'my_scrapy_project_directory.middlewares.ProxiesDownloaderMiddleware': 600,
},
```

That is it, now proxy will be applied to every request

Method 2:

Just enable `HttpProxyMiddleware` in `settings.py` and then do this for each request

```
yield Request(url=..., meta={'proxy': 'user:pass@host:port'})
```

Comment: Where do I find the value for `myproject`?

Comment: @rom its root directory name of your Scrapy project

Comment: sorry, can you give example?

Comment: @rom its name of folder where your scrapy project is in, its that simple

Comment: @UmairAyub, some scrapy projects are done without this template form. In case anyone else is interested you have to create ```$ scrapy startproject <your-project-name>```

Answer (score 3):

In Windows I put together a couple of previous answers and it worked. I simply did:

```
C:>  set http_proxy = http://username:password@proxy:port
```

and then I launched my program:

```
C:/.../RightFolder> scrapy crawl dmoz
```

where "dmzo" is the program name (I'm writing it because it's the one you find in a tutorial on internet, and if you're here you have probably started from the tutorial).

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend you to use a middleware such as [scrapy-proxies](https://github.com/aivarsk/scrapy-proxies). You can **rotate proxies, filter bad proxies or use a single proxy** for all your request. Also,using a middleware will save you the trouble of setting up proxy on every run.

This is directly from the GitHub README.

- Install the scrapy-rotating-proxy library

  `pip install scrapy_proxies`
- In your settings.py add the following settings

```
# Retry many times since proxies often fail
RETRY_TIMES = 10
# Retry on most error codes since proxies fail for different reasons
RETRY_HTTP_CODES = [500, 503, 504, 400, 403, 404, 408]

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': 90,
    'scrapy_proxies.RandomProxy': 100,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
}

# Proxy list containing entries like
# http://host1:port
# http://username:password@host2:port
# http://host3:port
# ...
PROXY_LIST = '/path/to/proxy/list.txt'

# Proxy mode
# 0 = Every requests have different proxy
# 1 = Take only one proxy from the list and assign it to every requests
# 2 = Put a custom proxy to use in the settings
PROXY_MODE = 0

# If proxy mode is 2 uncomment this sentence :
#CUSTOM_PROXY = "http://host1:port"
```

Here you can change **retry times**, set a **single  or rotating proxy**

- Then add your proxy to a list.txt file like this

```
http://host1:port
http://username:password@host2:port
http://host3:port
```

After this all your requests for that project will be sent through proxy. Proxy is rotated for every request randomly. It will not affect concurrency.

**Note: if you donot want to use proxy. You can simply comment the [scrapy_proxy](https://github.com/aivarsk/scrapy-proxies) middleware line.**

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': 90,
#    'scrapy_proxies.RandomProxy': 100,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110,
}
```

**Happy crawling!!!**