# Remove the new line "\n" from base64 encoded strings in Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, base64

I'm trying to make a HTTPS connection in Python3 and when I try to encode my username and password the `base64` `encodebytes` method returns the encoded value with a new line character at the end "\n" and because of this I'm getting an error when I try to connect.

Is there a way to tell the `base64` library not to append a new line character when encoding or what is the best way to remove this new line character? I tried using the `replace` method but I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data_consumer.py", line 33, in <module>
    auth_base64 = auth_base64.replace('\n', '')
TypeError: expected bytes, bytearray or buffer compatible object
```

My code:

```
auth = b'username@domain.com:passWORD'
auth_base64 = base64.encodebytes(auth)
auth_base64 = auth_base64.replace('\n', '')
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 74, accepted):

Instead of `encodestring` consider using `b64encode`. Later does not add `\n` characters. e.g.

```
In [11]: auth = b'username@domain.com:passWORD'

In [12]: base64.encodestring(auth)
Out[12]: b'dXNlcm5hbWVAZG9tYWluLmNvbTpwYXNzV09SRA==\n'

In [13]: base64.b64encode(auth)
Out[13]: b'dXNlcm5hbWVAZG9tYWluLmNvbTpwYXNzV09SRA=='
```

It produces identical encoded string except the `\n`

Comment: @SevenDays ``base64.b64encode(auth)`` works with python3 and ``base64.standard_b64encode(auth)`` seems to return the same result.

Comment: Note: In Python 3, `base64.standard_b64encode(s)` is defined as `return b64encode(s)`, so calling `base64.b64encode(s)` is fine.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html: "The legacy interface `base64.encodebytes(s)` only supports the Base64 standard alphabet, and it adds newlines every 76 characters as per RFC 2045. Note that if you are looking for RFC 2045 support you probably want to be looking at the email package instead."

Answer (score 6):

Following code would work

```
auth_base64 = auth_base64.decode('utf-8').replace('\n', '')
```

Answer (score 5):

For Python 3 use:

```
binascii.b2a_base64(cipher_text, newline=False)
```

For Python 2 use:

```
binascii.b2a_base64(cipher_text)[:-1]
```

Comment: This hint worked for me, early in my project I started out using the base64 library but encountered assorted problems embedding encoded images and sounds in webpages, so I switched to the codec library which worked fine until I tried encoding fonts due to the newlines. Switching to binascii has resolved all these issues. I include my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I concur with [Mandar's observation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32243566/728675) that `base64.xxxx_encode()` would produce output without line wrap `\n`.

For those who want a more confident understanding than merely an observation, these are the official promise (sort of), that I can find on this topic. The [Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/base64.html#base64.encode) does mention `base64.encode(...)` would add newlines after every 76 bytes of output. Comparing to that, all other `*_encode(...)` functions do not mention their linewrap behavior at all, which can argurably be considered as "no line wrap behavior". For what it's worth, the [Python 2 documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/base64.html) does not mention anything about line wrap at all.

Answer (score 2):

I applied @Harsh hint and these two functions to encode and decode binary data work for my application. My requirement is to be able to use data URIs in HTML src elements and CSS @font-face statements to represent binary objects, specifically images, sounds and fonts. These functions work.

```
import binascii

def string_from_binary(binary): 
    return binascii.b2a_base64(binary, newline=False).decode('utf-8')

def string_to_binary(string): 
    return binascii.a2b_base64(string.encode('utf-8'))
```