# Scrapy proxy ip does not work with https, returns 'ssl handshake failure'

Tags: python, twisted, scrapy, pyopenssl

Scrapy works with my proxy ip for an http request but not for an http**s** request.

I know my proxy IP is working with http because I test it by sending a request to http://ipinfo.io/ip:

```
2016-03-28 12:10:42 [scrapy] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://ipinfo.io/ip> (referer: http://www.google.com)
2016-03-28 12:10:42 [root] INFO:  *** TEST, WHAT IS MY IP: ***
107.183.7.XX
```

I know its not working with an https request because of this error message:

```
2016-03-28 12:10:55 [scrapy] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET https://www.my-company-url.com> (failed 3 times): [<twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('SSL routines', 'ssl23_read', 'ssl handshake failure')]>]
```

My `settings.py` contains:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'crystalball.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 100,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 110
}
```

My `crystalball.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware` contains:

```
import base64

class ProxyMiddleware(object):

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        request.meta['proxy'] = "https://107.183.X.XX:55555"
        proxy_user_pass = "hXXbp3:LitSwDXX99"
        encoded_user_pass = base64.encodestring(proxy_user_pass)
        request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + encoded_user_pass
```

Any suggestions on what I should experiment with next?

Side note: The solutions on this SO post have not worked: [Scrapy and proxies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710483/scrapy-and-proxies).

Answer (score 4):

The culprit is `base64.encodestring()`, which adds an unwanted new line `\n` character into the value of the Proxy-Authorization header of the request.

The solution was simply to `strip()` off that `\n`.

Change this line:

```
request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + encoded_user_pass
```

To this:

```
request.headers['Proxy-Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + encoded_user_pass.strip()
```