# How to use proxy in python script?

Tags: python, scrapy

How to use proxy in `python` web scraping script that can scrape the data from amazon. I need to learn how to use the proxy with below script
the script is here

```
import scrapy
from urls import start_urls
import re

class BbbSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
    name = 'bbb_spider'
    # start_urls = ['http://www.bbb.org/chicago/business-reviews/auto-repair-and-service-equipment-and-supplies/c-j-auto-parts-in-chicago-il-88011126']

  
    def start_requests(self):
        for x in start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(x, self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        
        brickset = str(response)
        NAME_SELECTOR = 'normalize-space(.//div[@id="titleSection"]/h1[@id="title"]/span[@id="productTitle"]/text())'
        #PAGELINK_SELECTOR = './/div[@class="info"]/h3[@class="n"]/a/@href'
        ASIN_SELECTOR = './/table/tbody/tr/td/div[@class="content"]/ul/li[./b[text()="ASIN: "]]//text()'
        #LOCALITY = 'normalize-space(.//div[@class="info"]/div/p/span[@class="locality"]/text())'
        #PRICE_SELECTOR = './/div[@id="price"]/table/tbody/tr/td/span[@id="priceblock_ourprice"]//text()'
        PRICE_SELECTOR = '#priceblock_ourprice'
        STOCK_SELECTOR = 'normalize-space(.//div[@id="availability"]/span/text())'
        PRODUCT_DETAIL_SELECTOR = './/table//div[@class="content"]/ul/li//text()'
        PRODUCT_DESCR_SELECTOR = 'normalize-space(.//div[@id="productDescription"]/p/text())'
        IMAGE_URL_SELECTOR = './/div[@id="imgTagWrapperId"]/img/@src'

        yield {
            'name': response.xpath(NAME_SELECTOR).extract_first().encode('utf8'),
            'pagelink': response.url,
            #'asin' : str(re.search("<li><b>ASIN: </b>([A-Z0-9]+)</li>",brickset).group(1).strip()),
            'price' : str(response.css(PRICE_SELECTOR).extract_first().encode('utf8')),
            'stock' : str(response.xpath(STOCK_SELECTOR).extract_first()),
            'product_detail' : str(response.xpath(PRODUCT_DETAIL_SELECTOR).extract()),
            'product_description' : str(response.xpath(PRODUCT_DESCR_SELECTOR).extract()),
            'img_url' : str(response.xpath(IMAGE_URL_SELECTOR).extract_first()),
        }
```

and the `start_url` file is here

```
start_urls = ['https://www.amazon.co.uk/d/Hair-Care/Loreal-Majirel-Hair-Colour-Tint-Golden-Mahogany/B0085L50QU', 'https://www.amazon.co.uk/d/Hair-Care/Michel-Mercier-Ultimate-Detangling-Wooden-Brush-Normal/B00TE1WH7U']
```

Comment: possible duplicate? : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710483/scrapy-and-proxies

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know,there are two ways to use proxy for Python code:

- Set the environment variables `http_proxy` and `https_proxy`,maybe it's the easiest way to use proxy.

  Windows:

  ```
  set http_proxy=http://proxy.myproxy.com  
  set https_proxy=https://proxy.myproxy.com  
  python get-pip.py
  ```

  Linux/OS X:

  ```
  export http_proxy=http://proxy.myproxy.com
  export https_proxy=https://proxy.myproxy.com
  sudo -E python get-pip.py
  ```
- Support for HTTP proxies is provided since Scrapy 0.8 through the HTTP Proxy downloader middleware. ,you can check out [HttpProxyMiddleware](http://scrapy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware).

  This middleware sets the HTTP proxy to use for requests, by setting the proxy meta value for `Request` objects.

  Like the Python standard library modules urllib and urllib2, it obeys the following environment variables:

  ```
  http_proxy
  https_proxy
  no_proxy
  ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need to use HTTP proxies in above script

Comment: @McGrady gave you a solution for the script, the middleware is the way to go

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do inside code.

Do this.

```
def start_requests(self):
    for x in start_urls:
        req = scrapy.Request(x, self.parse)
        req.meta['proxy'] = 'your_proxy_ip_here'
        yield req
```

And don't forget to put this in `settings.py` file

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 1,
}
```