# How to setting proxy in Python Scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I've use Python 2.7 and Scrapy 1.3.0

and I need set proxy to access web

how to set it?

this is my script in parse

```
if theurl not in self.ProcessUrls:
   self.ProcessUrls.append(theurl)
   yield scrapy.Request(theurl, callback=self.parse)
```

if i need to confirm the crawl new is not repeat how to do it? if not repeat need to crawl this new url

Comment: I can't set environment variable, it will affect other service and job,can i just setting it on scrapy Script?

Comment: See the second answer in the link above

Comment: where can i  set request.meta?

Answer (score 4):

We can use the following:

```
request = Request(url="http://example.com")
request.meta['proxy'] = "host:port"
yield request
```

A simple implementation is like below:

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "examplespider"
    allowed_domains = ["somewebsite.com"]
    start_urls = ['http://somewebsite.com/']

    def parse(self, response):
        # Here example.com is used. We usually get this URL by parsing desired webpage
        request = scrapy.Request(url='example.com', callback=self.parse_url)
        request.meta['proxy'] = "host:port"
        yield request

    def parse_url(self, response):
        # Do rest of the parsing work
        pass
```

If you want to use the proxy in initial:

Add the following as spider class field

```
class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
        name = "examplespider"
        allowed_domains = ["somewebsite.com"]
        start_urls = ['http://somewebsite.com/']
        custom_settings = {
        'HTTPPROXY_ENABLED': True
    }
```

And then use `start_requests()` method as below:

```
    def start_requests(self):
        urls = ['example.com']
        for url in urls:
            proxy = 'some proxy'
            yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse, meta={'proxy': proxy})

    def parse(self, response):
        item = StatusCehckerItem()
        item['url'] = response.url
        return item
```

Comment: can i setting the proxy on initial?

Comment: where can i add custom_settings ?

Comment: where can i get the HTML response? parse? the parse function is under start_request?

Comment: can i just use start_urls ? urls = ['example.com'] can i do this ?urls = self.start_urls ?

Comment: Yes you can do that. Also the parse function is not inside the start_requests function. See the edit. Also you can find html inside parse function

Comment: this is my script  if theurl not in self.ProcessUrls:
                               self.ProcessUrls.append(theurl)
                               yield scrapy.Request(theurl, callback=self.parse)
if i need to confirm the crawl new is not repeat how to do it?

Comment: Cannot understand this in comment. Please update your question.

Comment: I've update my question

Comment: did you have any idea?

Comment: I got ```/scrapy/core/downloader/webclient.py", line 22, in _parsed_url_args
    assert parsed.hostname is not None```. Can proxy causes this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set `http_proxy`, `https_proxy` environment variable. Refer this: [proxy for scrapy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710483/scrapy-and-proxies)

Comment: I can't set environment variable, it will affect other service and job,can i just setting it on scrapy Script?

Comment: Have you tried this [scrapy_proxies](https://github.com/aivarsk/scrapy-proxies)

Comment: Yes, I've try this one, but I don't know DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES is value is for what? and If I just have one proxy need to setting it's still need to read the text file ?