# How to proxy in Scrapy crawler?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I am trying to crawl a website which is only accessible via a proxy. I have created a project called scrapy_crawler using Scrapy and the structure is as follows:

[image: project structure]

I have read that I need to enable the HttpProxyMiddleware in settings.py.

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {   
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 100
}
```

I am a bit lost after that. I think I need to include the proxy in the request but I am not sure where to do that. I have tried the following in the middlewares.py file.

```
 def process_start_requests(self, start_requests, spider):
    # Called with the start requests of the spider, and works
    # similarly to the process_spider_output() method, except
    # that it doesn’t have a response associated.

    # Must return only requests (not items).
    for r in start_requests:
        r.meta['proxy'] = 'http://username:password@myproxy:port'
        yield r
```

And here is the digtionary.py file for reference.

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

class ImdbCrawler(CrawlSpider):
  name = 'digtionary'
  allowed_domains = ['www.mywebsite.com']
  start_urls = ['https://mywebsite.com/digital/pages/start.aspx#']
  rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor()),)
```

Any kind of help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scrapy and proxies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710483/scrapy-and-proxies)

Comment: Hello, yes I have tried this but I forgot to mention that I need to parse a username and password too. Is there any way of doing that? Thanks

Comment: https://www.zyte.com/blog/scrapy-proxy/ if you need proxy authorization.