# python Scrapy framework adding to my code proxy

Tags: python, proxy, scrapy

I am trying new feature for myself as adding proxy port to my python scraper code.

I took free proxy from this [site](https://scrapingant.com/free-proxies/), and looked for an answer from [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710483/scrapy-and-proxies). With help of user @dskrypa I changed in my code `meta={'proxy':'103.42.162.50:8080'}`

Now it gives an error which continues all along if I do not stop the code run.

```
File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\handlers\http11.py", line 279, in _get_agent
    proxyScheme, proxyNetloc, proxyHost, proxyPort, proxyParams = _parse(proxy)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\webclient.py", line 39, in _parse
    return _parsed_url_args(parsed)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\webclient.py", line 20, in _parsed_url_args
    host = to_bytes(parsed.hostname, encoding="ascii")
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\scrapy\utils\python.py", line 108, in to_bytes
    raise TypeError('to_bytes must receive a str or bytes '
TypeError: to_bytes must receive a str or bytes object, got NoneType
2023-03-12 02:47:32 [scrapy.core.scraper] ERROR: Error downloading <GET https://dvlaregistrations.dvla.gov.uk/search/results.html?search=N11CKY&action=index&pricefrom=0&priceto=&prefixmatches=&currentmatches=&limitprefix=&limitcurrent=&limitauction=&searched=true&openoption=&language=en&prefix2=Search&super=&super_pricefrom=&super_priceto=>
```

Here is my code;

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import pandas as pd
import scrapy_xlsx

itemList=[]
class plateScraper(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scrapePlate'
    allowed_domains = ['dvlaregistrations.dvla.gov.uk']
    FEED_EXPORTERS = {'xlsx': 'scrapy_xlsx.XlsxItemExporter'}
    custom_settings = {'FEED_EXPORTERS' :FEED_EXPORTERS,'FEED_FORMAT': 'xlsx','FEED_URI': 'output_r00.xlsx', 'LOG_LEVEL':'INFO','DOWNLOAD_DELAY': 0}
    DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
        'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy.HttpProxyMiddleware': 1
    }

    def start_requests(self):
        df=pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
        columnA_values=df['PLATE']
        for row in columnA_values:
            global  plate_num_xlsx
            plate_num_xlsx=row
            base_url =f"https://dvlaregistrations.dvla.gov.uk/search/results.html?search={plate_num_xlsx}&action=index&pricefrom=0&priceto=&prefixmatches=&currentmatches=&limitprefix=&limitcurrent=&limitauction=&searched=true&openoption=&language=en&prefix2=Search&super=&super_pricefrom=&super_priceto="
            url=base_url
            yield scrapy.Request(url,callback=self.parse, cb_kwargs={'plate_num_xlsx': plate_num_xlsx},meta={'proxy':'103.42.162.50:8080'})

    def parse(self, response, plate_num_xlsx=None):
        plate = response.xpath('//div[@class="resultsstrip"]/a/text()').extract_first()
        price = response.xpath('//div[@class="resultsstrip"]/p/text()').extract_first()

        try:
            a = plate.replace(" ", "").strip()
            if plate_num_xlsx == plate.replace(" ", "").strip():
                item = {"plate": plate_num_xlsx, "price": price.strip()}
                itemList.append(item)
                print(item)
                yield item
            else:
                item = {"plate": plate_num_xlsx, "price": "-"}
                itemList.append(item)
                print(item)
                yield item
        except:
            item = {"plate": plate_num_xlsx, "price": "-"}
            itemList.append(item)
            print(item)
            yield item

process = CrawlerProcess()
process.crawl(plateScraper)
process.start()

import winsound
winsound.Beep(555,333)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with scrapy, but the `meta='103.42.162.50:8080'` argument to `scrapy.Request(...)` is what is causing that error.  It expects a different data type for that parameter.  From the linked question, it looks like it should be `meta={'proxy': '103.42.162.50:8080'}`

Comment: now it gives totally different error. and traceback continues long. Thanks for your assisance by the way)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should include the protocol in the proxy url:

```py
meta={"proxy": "http://103.42.162.50:8080"}
```

Comment: Wow. It enormously slowed down my speed, I was guessing it will improve though

Comment: yeah adding a proxy usually lowers speed because your request has to go to the proxy first before going to it's destination. It's also because these public proxies are low quality so if you want something better consider paid proxy services

Comment: I would like to pay, but I am not blocked, I needed proxies for better speed. Now, without proxy it runs better, much more accelerated.